# how update the helm installation of istio to enable 'Kubernetes Ingress with Cert-Manager' or 'enable SDS at ingress gateway'

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio

Install isito in eks cluster using helm as follows:
helm install istio --namespace istio-system --set grafana.enabled=true --set kiali.enabled=true --set prometheus.enabled=true --set tracing.enabled=true istio.io/istio

But didn't enable the 'sds' and found that by default it false.
It will be possible to update the istio installation with helm to enable sds or I have to redo everything again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use helm [upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/#helm-upgrade) and pass the desired parameters as part of that command.

Answer (score 0):

As @Argya Sadhu mentioned you can

> Use helm [upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/#helm-upgrade) and pass the desired parameters as part of that command.

---

I would add few things to his answer.

---

### helm installation options

**There** is istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/installation-options/#gateways-options) with helm installation options, you can find your desired parameters mentioned by @Argya Sadhu here.

---

### Istio documentation about sds, ingress with cert-menager

If you take a look at this istio documentation 1.5 everything is done with istioctl, but you still should be able to do it with helm.

- https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/#before-you-begin
- https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-sds/

If you take a look at older istio docs, for example 1.2, they use helm there instead.

- https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/
- https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-sds/

---

### Additional informations

As  mentioned in istio documentation [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/helm/)

> The Helm installation approach will be deprecated in the future. We recommend Installing with istioctl, instead.

If you think about using istio for longer time I would suggest to take a look at [istioctl](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/istioctl/) or [istio operator](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/).

---

Hope you find this useful.